# Product of a bounded (not necessarily convergent) sequence $(a_n)$ and a convergent sequence $(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am self-learning Real Analysis from Stephen Abott's `Understanding Analysis`. Exercise 2.3.9 poses couple of questions about the product of a bounded (not necessarily convergent) sequence $(a_n)$ and a convergent sequence $(b_n)$. I wasn't quite sure, if my conclusion of part (b) is accurate. So, it'll be real nice, if you guys could verify my solution.

> Problem 2.3.9
>
> (a) Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded (not necessarily convergent) sequence, and assume $\lim b_n = 0$. Show that $\lim (a_n b_n) = 0$. Why are we not allowed to use the Algebraic limit theorem to prove this?
>
> (b) Can we conclude anything about the convergence of $(a_n b_n)$, if we assume that $(b_n)$ converges to some non-zero limit $b$?

***Proof.***

$\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$

(a) We are given that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence. There exists a larrge number $M > 0 $, such that

\begin{align*}
  \absval{a_n} < M
 \end{align*}

for all $n$.

Also, we have $\lim b_n = 0$. Pick a small arbitrary but fixed positive real number $\epsilon > 0$. There exists an $N_\epsilon$ such that,

\begin{align*}
  \absval{b_n} < \frac{\epsilon}{M}
 \end{align*}

for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$.

Observe that,

\begin{align*}
  \absval{a_n b_n - 0} &= \absval{a_n}\cdot \absval{b_n}\\
  &< M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon
 \end{align*}

Hence, $\absval{a_n b_n - 0} < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$.

Consequently, $\lim(a_n b_n) = 0$.

We are not allowed to use Algebraic limit theorem to prove this, because Algebraic limit theorem applies to two convergent sequences.

(b) Suppose $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence and $(b_n)$ converges to some non-zero limit $b$. We can prove that $(a_n b_n)$ is also a bounded (not necessarily a convergent sequence).

Since, $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then there exists a large number $M > 0$, such that

\begin{align*}
  \absval{a_n} < M
 \end{align*}

Since, $(b_n) \to b$, we can make the distance $\absval{b_n - b}$ as small as we like. Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. There exists an $N_\epsilon \in \mathbf{N}$, such that

\begin{align*}
  \absval{b_n - b} < \epsilon
 \end{align*}

Clearly, if $b_n$ eventually lies in the interval $(b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, we have $\absval{b_n} < \absval{b} + \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$.

Thus, we find that

\begin{align*}
  \absval{a_n b_n} &= \absval{a_n} \cdot \absval {b_n} \\
  &< M \cdot (\absval{b} + \epsilon)
 \end{align*}

for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$. But, what about the terms of the sequence $(a_n b_n)$ preceding $N_\epsilon$? There are only a finite number of them. If we choose $K = \max \{ \absval {a_1 b_1}, \absval {a_2 b_2}, \ldots, M(\absval {b} + \epsilon) \}$, then

\begin{align*}
  \absval{a_n b_n} < K
 \end{align*}

for all $n$.

In the special case that, $(a_n)$ is also convergent, then it follows using the algebraic limit theorem, $(a_n b_n)$ also converges.

Comment: You can simplify proof of (b) just by taking a concrete value of $\varepsilon$ (for expmple, $\varepsilon=1$). Moreoveer, you should give an example of nonconvergence (for example, $a_n=1-(-1)^n$ and $b_n=1$).

Comment: The proof is fine for me. You could also add examples like $\sin(n)(1/n+a)$.

Comment: Good to see you're still grinding after half a decade quasar. you'll make a great quant